# Data Studio Connector - getting more helpful messages for debugging

Tags: looker-studio

I am building out a google data studio connector, however its not clear where the error is.

Is it possible to get specific error messages from the data studio connector about what the issue is thats not working.

Instead of just a generic..

````
```
There was an error caused by the community connector. Please report the issue to the provider of this community connector if this issue persists.

Connector details
There was an error caused by this connector.

Error ID: b8104ea6
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [error handling and messages guide](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/error-handling) provides details on how to show errors to users for your connector. Among several other things, you should ensure `isAdminUser()` returns `true` for the developer(yourself).

Answer (score 7):

Adding this code helped in my case:

```
function isAdminUser() {
  return true;
}
```

Found the solution here:

- [Building a custom Google Data Studio connector from A-Z. Part 1 — Basic setup.](https://medium.com/@bajena3/building-a-custom-google-data-studio-connector-from-a-z-part-1-basic-setup-445a6d965d3f)

Answer (score 0):

Below statement is from google https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/error-handling

Implement `isAdminUser()` to identify admins so the right level of detail is shown to connector users.

This should solve the problem.

As Max Makhrov answered above. Add `function isAdminUser() { return true; }`